# Required Accounts In SharePoint Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, deployment, sharepoint-on-prem, prerequisites

SharePoint server requires 3 user accounts. A SQL Server service account, a setup user account and a server farm account.

For a testing environment, should these accounts be separate/different accounts or is using a single domain account to do all 3 functions acceptable?

I'm encountering an issue where the server farm account, which acts as the application pool identity, is showing up as the "SHAREPOINT\System" account, with limited permissions and no ability to elevate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use your account you're browsing sites with as one of the service accounts (e.g. Farm or Web App Pool account). Certain features will fail with the note that you received regarding `SHAREPOINT\system`.

Comment: So, using one domain account to do all 3 roles (SQL Server service account, setup account, and server farm account) would be okay in a test environment, as long as it's not the account I'm browsing from/using as the admin?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. I generally recommend test environments (unless it is temporary or a developer's personal environment) follow production rules to make it as production alike as possible.

Answer (score 1):

For testing / development, it is ok to use the single account for every thing. I am doing it the same way. For lower environment it is always killer to have too many accounts.

Where you are seeing that error or what error?

Comment: I am using my personal domain account for all 3 roles. When the SharePoint Server configuration is completed, I received an error stating "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you". I noticed that when I log in, I am under the account SHAREPOINT\System, instead of my own username. I believe this is because my account is the application pool identity.

Comment: You mix the service accounts with user accounts. You should keep it separate, use a single services account for all 3 but use your account for browsing.